# RegEx search in Chrome network requests tab

Tags: regex, google-chrome, search, xmlhttprequest

Recently I've had a situation where I need to check 2 or 3 specific XHR requests in a web page workflow. I am working on a site that does a lot of other XHR requests so it's a little uncomfortable to either filter for each specific request or scroll around and find it and then filter for the next one or scroll for it.

An example would be something like:

Requests:

1. set_session_email
2. get_session_email
3. send_sync_info
4. send_sync_purchase_info

So, in order to filter all those I'd like to be able to add a simple RegEx like this:

```regex
(set_session_email|get_session_email|send_sync_info|send_sync_purchase_info)
```

The thing is that Chrome's network tab finds nothing when I handle it like that, so I am not sure if it requires some specific formatting or the search doesn't handle RegEx for the filter that tab.

Any ideas if this can be done and how? Or this should be a feature request for Chrome?

**EDIT**

Initially I mentioned search, but what I refer to is filter:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your expression with "/", e.g. use:

```
/(set_session_email|get_session_email|send_sync_info|send_sync_purchase_info)/
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try that before. Thanks!